# Divisibility of integers by integers

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We are given a number $$K(n) = (n+3) (n^2 + 6n + 8)$$ defined for integers n. The options suggest that the number K(n) should either always be divisible by 4, 5 or 6.

Factorizing the second bracket term, we get $$ K(n) = (n+3) (n + 2) (n+4)$$

i.e the number is always divisible by -4 -2 and -3. IMO that means that the number should always be divisible by 4 and 6. However the answer book states that the number is only divisible by 6. Why is not always divisible by 4?

Comment: what happens if $n=3$?

Comment: You've found the *roots* of the cubic $(\text{namely}\;-2, -3, -4),$ which aren't necessarily  *divisors* of the cubic.

Comment: Aaah, this might be really basic, but what is the difference between the root of the function and the divisor of the same?

Comment: @dexter A divisor of a function is a number $k$ such that $k\mid f(n)$ for all $n$. A root of a function is a number $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K(n)$ is the product of three consecutive integers. Therefor it's automatically divisible by $2$ and $3$, thus by $6$. $K(n)$ need not be divisible by $4$. Consider
$$K(3) = 5\cdot6\cdot7 = 210$$

In general, the product of $k$ consecutive integers is divisible by all natural numbers $n\le k$.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$, 
$$K(n)\equiv 6\cdot 5\cdot 7\equiv 2\cdot 1\cdot 3\equiv 2\not\equiv 0\pmod 4.$$

Answer (score 1):

$K(n)$ is the product of three consecutive numbers. If the first and the third are odd and the second is even (of course) but not a multiple of $4$, then $K(n)$ will not be a multiple of $4$ either.